# Reverse proxy in IIS, regex to match everything apart from two URL's..?

Tags: regex, iis, reverse-proxy

I need to have traffic to a domain reverse proxy to a different server. I'm using IIS and URL Rewrite, which is working fine.

However, I need to miss out two specific URL's from the reverse proxy (anything beginning with either `/payments` or `/paypal`).

So:

- `/` = match
- `/testing` = match
- `/testing/123/qwerty/something-else` = match
- `/payments` = **no match**
- `/payments/123` = **no match**
- `/paypal` = **no match**
- `/paypal/sandbox` = **no match**

I think I may need a "negative lookahead", but I have no idea where to start.

Can anyone help..?

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be as simple as this:

```
^\/(?!(payments|paypal)).*$
```

Meaning: 
`^` = start of string

`\/` = 1 `/`

`(?!(payments|paypal))` = negative look ahead

`.*` = anything (except payments or paypal)

`$` = end of string

see: https://regex101.com/r/xVg36K/1

Comment: Perfect, thank you! It turns out that IIS doesn't need the first `/` so I missed that out (`\/`) and it works exactly as I need.